# How hypervisors see the compute resources of underlying servers

Tags: cloud, hypervisor

In the server room where the virtual machines are "spinning" are three servers. One has two
processor with four cores, one with four processors with two cores and one server has only one
processor with eight cores.

- How hypervisors see each of these individual servers from the
  standpoint of compute resources?
- How does the fact that we have a
  server with a different number of physical processors and the same
  number of cores affects the processes of migration and starting
  virtual machines on other servers?

Thank you

Comment: Not a programming question, not a general thing (hypervisors are different).

Comment: Maybe it's not a programming question, but I think there is a general answer to this.

Comment: And since this is a programming forum, the answer may be elsewhere. Still, not every hypervisor will perform migrations the same way with same requirements.

Comment: Well, since this forum has both tags (cloud and hypervisor) I don't think that this question is inappropriate.

Comment: Tag names don't mean much. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic